# I bought a new IP address from my server host. How do I find out what that IP is...?

Tags: ip, vps, dhclient

I purchased an additional IP for my server a couple days back and I have no idea what that IP is. When purchasing the IP, the only email I received was a notice saying it will take between 24-48 hours for the IP to become usable.

Is there a way to scan for available IP addresses on Linux? Can dhclient list all IP's without assigning them to an NIC?

Comment: What you do is, you ASK them.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I ordered smoething fom Amazon yesterday. Can YOU tell me where it is?

Normal answer you would say is "*****, ask amazon". You wuold not say "Hey, go to some totally unrealted message board and ask people who have no way to know".

Same here. You ordered from them. Guess who knows what they gave you. THEY do.

Answer (score 3):

As a datacenter Operations Director - I will tell you GO TO YOUR ISP.
There are a ton of ways to do a port scan - HOWEVER chances are doing a port scan will be against your providers TOS and AUP (Terms of Service / Acceptable Use Policy)

We allow Port Scans by users to their own equipment - but routinely will disqualify traffic coming from IP Addresses doing port scans.

Our Control panel allows a user to perform a scan against their own server - as well as schedule various services such as Qualsys, McAfee, BluePay PCI etc... HOWEVER just random traffic will most assuredly for any DataCenter worth its weight in spit - get you into trouble.

We run a number of tools that would automagically kill your traffic.

CALL YOUR DATACENTER / ISP - or open a ticket.

If you are not running anything on your own server AND your ISP does not - it is time to get some security in place as well.

I suggest you check out www.ConfigServer.com for the CSF firewall and/or R-FX networks for APF/BFD as well.

Both are free

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no way without asking the provider, as most don't have a DHCP setup *quite* sophisticated enough to hand out IP addresses to specific machines in this manner (if they even have DHCP at all).